# How to write constraint which says if p or q then r in pyomo?

Tags: optimization, constraints, mathematical-optimization, pyomo

Hi I am learning optimization using pyomo and i have a problem where one variable should get value only when one of the other two variables or both get a value.

it's like (P V Q) => R in tautology. can someone please help how to write it as a constraint in pyomo.

example : if i am using 3 ingredients to make a product, 3rd one should always be used if any of 1,2 are used or both 1,2 are used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what "get a value" is in optimization. All variables in the model "get a value". Look at it as a system of equations + an objective.

But, of course,

```
 (P V Q) => R
```

is equivalent to

```
  R >= P
  R >= Q
```

where R,P and Q are binary variables.

Comment: i meant "p or q" implies r.  i didnt understand what R>=P is that R greater than or equal to P ??

Comment: Come on. Boolean variables can be considered as 0 or 1 (0=false, 1=true).

Comment: ohh make sense sorry. Thanks , i thinks this would do. I will try to implement this .

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is disjunctive programming. Pyomo provides support for that through Pyomo.GDP: https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modeling_extensions/gdp.html, with more logical expression support upcoming.

For simple problems, the direct algebraic formulation suggested by Erwin is probably easiest.